# Barcode reader mlkit - android kotlin

Tags: android, qr-code, barcode-scanner, android-camerax, google-mlkit

I am trying to implement barcode reader with new mlkit. I don't know what I am doing wrong here. I was following official guides:
https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/android
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started/#0

Also I cloned preview apps from official github page but there everything works like charm. No idea what is wrong here. I pass every frame to scan and also I do cleanup after processing image

```
typealias QrListener = (qrValue: String) -> Unit

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null

    private lateinit var outputDirectory: File
    private lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Request camera permissions
        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            startCamera()
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS
            )
        }

        // Setup the listener for take photo button
        camera_capture_button.setOnClickListener { takePhoto() }

        outputDirectory = getOutputDirectory()

        cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    }

    private fun takePhoto() {
        // Get a stable reference of the modifiable image capture use case
        val imageCapture = imageCapture ?: return

        // Create timestamped output file to hold the image
        val photoFile = File(
            outputDirectory,
            SimpleDateFormat(
                FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.US
            ).format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"
        )

        // Create output options object which contains file + metadata
        val outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photoFile).build()

        // Setup image capture listener which is triggered after photo has
        // been taken
        imageCapture.takePicture(
            outputOptions,
            ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
            object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
                override fun onError(exc: ImageCaptureException) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Photo capture failed: ${exc.message}", exc)
                }

                override fun onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                    val savedUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile)
                    val msg = "Photo capture succeeded: $savedUri"
                    Toast.makeText(baseContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    Log.d(TAG, msg)
                }
            })
    }

    private fun startCamera() {
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
            // Used to bind the lifecycle of cameras to the lifecycle owner
            val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

            // Preview
            val preview = Preview.Builder()
                .build()
                .also {
                    it.setSurfaceProvider(viewFinder.createSurfaceProvider())
                }

            imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
                .build()

            val imageAnalyzer = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                .build()
                .also {
                    it.setAnalyzer(cameraExecutor, QrAnalyzer { luma ->
                        Log.d(TAG, "Average luminosity: $luma")
                    })
                }

            // Select back camera as a default
            val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

            try {
                // Unbind use cases before rebinding
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()

                // Bind use cases to camera
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture, imageAnalyzer
                )

            } catch (exc: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
            }

        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }

    private fun allPermissionsGranted() = REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS.all {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            baseContext, it
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    private fun getOutputDirectory(): File {
        val mediaDir = externalMediaDirs.firstOrNull()?.let {
            File(it, resources.getString(R.string.app_name)).apply { mkdirs() }
        }
        return if (mediaDir != null && mediaDir.exists())
            mediaDir else filesDir
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        cameraExecutor.shutdown()
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults:
        IntArray
    ) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS) {
            if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
                startCamera()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Permissions not granted by the user.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
                finish()
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "CameraXBasic"
        private const val FILENAME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSS"
        private const val REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 10
        private val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    }
}

class QrAnalyzer(private val listener: QrListener) : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {

    private fun ByteBuffer.toByteArray(): ByteArray {
        rewind()    // Rewind the buffer to zero
        val data = ByteArray(remaining())
        get(data)   // Copy the buffer into a byte array
        return data // Return the byte array
    }

    @SuppressLint("UnsafeExperimentalUsageError")
    override fun analyze(image: ImageProxy) {

        val mediaImage = image.image
        if (mediaImage != null) {
            val img = InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, image.imageInfo.rotationDegrees)
            // Pass image to an ML Kit Vision API
            // ...
            scan(img)
        }

        image.close()
    }

    private fun scan(image: InputImage) {

        val options = BarcodeScannerOptions.Builder()
            .setBarcodeFormats(
                Barcode.FORMAT_ALL_FORMATS
            )
            .build()

        val scanner = BarcodeScanning.getClient(options)
        val result = scanner.process(image)
            .addOnSuccessListener { barcodes ->
                // Task completed successfully
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                // [START get_barcodes]
                for (barcode in barcodes) {
                    val bounds = barcode.boundingBox
                    val corners = barcode.cornerPoints

                    val rawValue = barcode.rawValue

                    val valueType = barcode.valueType
                    // See API reference for complete list of supported types
                    Log.v("TESTING: ", "Barcode detected: $rawValue")
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { }
            .addOnCompleteListener { }
    }
}
```

and my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test_mlkit"
        minSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress "tflite"
    }


}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:16.0.2'

    def camerax_version = "1.0.0-beta07"
// CameraX core library using camera2 implementation
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$camerax_version"
// CameraX Lifecycle Library
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$camerax_version"
// CameraX View class
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha14"
}


This are the logs I receive when run the app

W/mple.test_mlki: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/mple.test_mlki: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/mple.test_mlki: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/mple.test_mlki: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/mple.test_mlki: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
```

Comment: It is likely that you're closing the image before it gets processed. Remove the image.close() from the analyze method and put it inside the addOnSuccessListener

Comment: Yep! You was right but not on onSuccessListener but on the onCompletedListener. Lovely! Thanks!